# Как загрузить файл не используя file api

Tags: javascript, html

Как загрузить файл, не используя file api (в java-script)?

```
 if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported. 

 } else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
 }
```

Comment: iframe? но нужен скрипт на бэкенде

Comment: часть кода реализовано и работает через file api (далее передается серверу информация вида : размер\название\содержимое. )         Можно ли реализовать подобное, но только используя formdata ?

Comment: Добавил проверку поддержки file api браузером ( см. выше пример )